Primary key not being set using Laravel Eloquent
I am trying to use a model to create a table and have the AcctId field be the primary key.
class account extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    protected $table = 'accounts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AcctId';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}

after I
php artisan migrate:fresh

My Migration
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('AcctId');
        $table->string('AccountName');
        $table->string('Address');
        $table->string('City');
        $table->string('State');
        $table->string('Zip');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

It is still not making AcctId the primary key. What am I missing?


Show your migration file. Tables are added with migrations, not models.

Added..........

Change: $table->string('AcctId'); to $table->string('AcctId')->primary();

ohhh. thank you. I thought setting it in the model would do that for me.

bro, also your question is so confusing, use a model to create a table! have fun with coding ;)

It maybe wasn't the clearest question. Made sense to me! lol.  I thought, I could use the model to set the primary key when I ran the migration.

I thought setting it in the model would do that for me ... that only tells the model what the primary key is, if it's a value other than the expected default id, and since it's a string, the other properties that you set $incrementing = false; and $keyType = 'string' are necessary too.

I am happy to help you with this.
When you create a table in Laravel and define a primary key, you need to specify it explicitly using the primary method. So in your case, it would be like this:
$table->string('AcctId')->primary();

Here is the full migration code:
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('AcctId')->primary();
        $table->string('AccountName');
        $table->string('Address');
        $table->string('City');
        $table->string('State');
        $table->string('Zip');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

After making the following changes, run the PHP artisan migrate and it should create the accounts table with AcctId as the primary key.
